# Power BI change data source parameter

Tags: powerbi

Is it possible and how change data source parameter value with slicer or check box click in power bi without manual edit and then refresh data.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't possible. However, you can make a report which connects and reads all the data sources, and use a [What-if parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-what-if) with slicer to calculate result based on one of the data sources only (depending on the what-if parameter's value).